# "Non-constant operand in constant expression error" in Cygwin using rgbasm

Tags: cygwin

I'm attempting to run a "make" command in Cygwin to create a .gbc file (for gameboy color emulator) and am getting an error from the wram.asm file (line 3151).  As best as I understand, rgbasm and its counterparts are used somewhere in the compile process.  Here is the relevant section:

SECTION "Sound Stack", WRAMX

**wSoundStack:: ds SOUND_STATE_SIZE * SOUND_STACK_CAPACITY**

wSoundStackSize:: db

I'm guessing the "non-constant operand in constant expression" error is due to the *, but I don't know how to fix it.  I changed it to "-" in order to get it to work, but I'm sure the program will crash at some point as a result...  It's for personal enjoyment, so while it's arguably irresponsible to do so, I needed to for the sake of temporary sanity.

I apologize for using any terms incorrectly; I don't have much programming knowledge and was just interested in editing simple text values and then compiling under the assumption the rest of the files were clean to compile.

Comment: what type of asm is expected and which assembler are you using ? What is the make output ? It should show the failed command

Answer (score 0):

After getting fed up with no answer, I just said screw it and deleted the entry (the empty line is still there).

After building it (it took a good 10-15 min. on my end), it seemed to run with no problems. I did a side-by-side comparison with the build and the release, and the only difference was at address 14E-14F. (Build: 87CD Release: 8899)

So, if anything goes wrong, I guess change the value of the build's address to the release's.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is not a valid operator in rgbasm. You have to use the `MUL(x,y)` function.